# How to model JPA relationship for below entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have a Table1 which stores meta info on different type of lists(ListA,ListB, etc) and another Table2 to relate list type and its contents(ManyToOne). Also have a link Table3 which stores relationship between each list item in Table2, in this Table3 each list item can only associate to one parent from Table2.

1. List A Item's
   a1
   a2
   a3
2. List B Item's
   b1
   b2
   b3

Table 3 Stores
*a1-b1*,
*a1-b2*,
*a1-b3*
but will not have(a2-b1,a2-b2,a2-b3 relationship).

Not sure how to model JPA join  for a given input parent id (for ex:a1) query  Table3 return all associated children details and its associated Parent.

Dont want to do a select on Table3 for that Id(:a1) and then link it to Table 2 using (**ExitsIn**) **spring-data** to get Children details.

Please suggest better way to do it, this way its very slow.

Comment: Why can you not query Table2 based on Id(:a1) and then ask it to eagerly load the @OneToMany relationship with Table3 as a part of your query?

Comment: I was able to do away with using ManyToMany on Table2 Entity with Table 3, which maintains relationship. Has List of items self refrencing Table2 entities,